# How to calculate this limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let $$a_n \colon= \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Then how to decide about the convergence or otherwise of the sequence $(a_n)$? And if this sequence IS convergent, then how to determine 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n?$$

Comment: Hint: Stirling approximation.

Comment: or calculate $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

Answer (score 2):

It's trivial to notice by **Cauchy-D'Alembert criterion** that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=e \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\approx \frac{e}{n}$$

and hence the conclusion.

**Q.E.D.**

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** You may rewrite
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=e^{-\Large \frac{\log(n!)}{n}}
$$
and, as $n$ tends to $+\infty$, use [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)
$$
n!= \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left({n \over e}\right)^n
\left(1+ \mathcal{O}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)$$

to obtain 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=\frac en+\mathcal{O}{\left(\frac{\ln n}{n^2}\right)}
$$ giving an easy conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

**hint:** a consequence of the Stirling formula is:
$$
\log n! \sim n \log n
$$